# Combobox options not changing when datasource updated

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

So the data is loaded properly when I use this method in the Main Window Constructor:

```
public void Load_Dropdown(configuration con)
{
    bindinglist = new BindingList<ListCollection.ListsList>(Get.ListCollection(con).List);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource {DataSource = bindinglist};
    sharepointListSelect.DataSource = bSource;
    sharepointListSelect.DisplayMember = "Title";
    sharepointListSelect.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

And this works fine, but when I try to call a similar method to update the options at a later time, nothing happens- as in the options in the drop down do not change.

The method I call to update it looks like this:

```
public bool Reload_Dropdown(configuration con)
{            
    bindinglist = new BindingList<ListCollection.ListsList>(Get.ListCollection(con).List);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = bindinglist };
    sharepointListSelect.DataSource = bSource; 
    sharepointListSelect.DisplayMember = "Title";
    sharepointListSelect.ValueMember = "ID";


    //There is other logic here, but i left it out as it isn't relevant
    return true;
}
```

Btw, the binding list object is initialized in the class as:

```
private BindingList<ListCollection.ListsList> bindinglist;
```

I know, right now I can reuse the first method- but I split up the declaration to debug why it is failing the update in the first place.

Comment: Consider posting [MCVE]. At first step creating MCVE will help you to find and solve the problem. If you could't solve the problem yourself, then it will help other user to reproduce the problem to help you.  Also instead of creating different instance of `BindingSource` over and over again, just use drop a single `BindingSource` on your form at design time and use it.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. It was an oversight on my part, and I will make an answer to describe how I dealt with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid- So the issue isn't with either method, but how I was calling the method. You cannot call a method from another form if it isn't static. Huge oversight on my part- a bit too accustomed to MVC I suppose.

This solution will work fine, so long as you call it from within the same method. I opted to just have a button that will refresh the dropdown.